# The way to reduce Cached Memory by structures in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I've been using some structures to cache some temporary list.
And, I'd like to find some solutions to reduce allocated memory as maintaining the performance.
Structure's components are below.

```
structure LatestInfo
{
        std::string visitedWebsites;
        std::string watchedVideo;
        std::string userId;
        std::string userName;
        unsigned int lastLoginTime;
        std::string contentsRating;
        //and so on
}
```

And I have `std::vector<LatestInfo> latestList` to store `LatestInfo` structure.

There are many `LastestInfo` in `latestList` and it is getting bigger.

So, it allocate a lot of memory (more than 200Mbs) in our system.

Not only `LatestInfo`is updated regularly(every 2 hours), but also the performance is very important, we're storing some fixed value in DB(SQLite) only.

So, I'd like to reduce its allocated memory without using a DB.

IMO, if std::string can be compressed, it would be good and require minimum changes.
Do you know some open sources or libraries to compress it to reduce allocated memory?

or better solutions you have?

Thank you.

Comment: "Do you know some open sources or libraries to compress it to reduce allocated memory?" - Note; asking for library recommendations etc is *off-topic* here.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl. It sounds like that. I agree. But, if I use several libraries or my own solutuin and share the profiling results it may be proper topic here I think. Thanks

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I got a good results by flyweight pattern

Answer (score 1):

If your strings have a lot of duplicates, you can use “string interning” where you only have one copy of the string data, and then pointers back to it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Here is a C++ library that does it for you (I haven’t used this one, just showed up in my google search):
https://github.com/RipcordSoftware/libstringintern

Comment: Sounds like a flyweight pattern: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html

Comment: It may be proper to my cases, I'll apply it and share results soon. Thank yiu

Comment: @Evg and Buddy, yours idea saved my time and I got effective results :)

Answer (score 1):

I got an effective results with flyweight.
Solution is simple as below.

```
#include <boost/flyweight.hpp>
structure LatestInfo
{
        flyweight<std::string> visitedWebsites;
        flyweight<std::string> watchedVideo;
        flyweight<std::string> userId;
        flyweight<std::string> userName;
        flyweight<std::string> lastLoginTime;
        flyweight<std::string> contentsRating;
        //and so on
}

std::map<unsigned int, LatestInfo> userMap;   //index per LatestInfo
```

For more information,
My data has about `total 12,000 LatestInfo` and there are many duplicate string.

> For example,
>   Especially visitedWebsites(latest) which includes url.
>   Average length of url is about 100, and 80 percent of url were duplicated.

`So, I save my cached memory about 1MB in url, and total 5 MB was saved after applying flyweight.`

Even though Flyweight Pattern might make slower the program, I removed the inefficient logics such as unnecessary copy and success to maintain a performance.

> Please note that boost flyweight patterns maintain the data while the object alive.